# Multi-indexing plotting with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to graph multi indexing plot using matplotlib. However, I was struggling to find the exact code from the previously answered code. Can anyone assist me how can I produce similar graph.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl 
import numpy as np
import pandas 

xls_filename = "abc.xlsx"
f = pandas.ExcelFile(xls_filename)
df = f.parse("Sheet1", index_col='Year' and 'Month')
f.close()

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})  # Font size of x and y-axis
df.plot(kind= 'bar', alpha=0.70)
```

It is not indexing as I wanted and not produced the graph as expected as well. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I created a DataFrame from some of the values I see on your attached plot and plotted it.

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples=[(2011, ), (2012, ), (2016, 'M'), (2016, 'J')], names=['year', 'month'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data={'1': [10, 140, 6, 9], '2': [23, 31, 4, 5], '3': [33, 23, 1, 1]})
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

This is the outcome

[image]

where the DataFrame is this

[image]

Comment: Hi @Uğur Güney, thanks. Any idea how to eliminate the NaN from the graph. I tried df[~np.isnan(df)] where df is the current dataframe.

Comment: Hi! `np.isnan(df)` or `df.isnan()` checks only the values of a dataframe, not its indices. And if you look at the month level index via `df.index.levels[1]` you see that there are no None's in there. I guess those NaNs appear only when the df table is displayed.

I put single quotes to month section instead of leaving it empty when creating the tuples: `tuples=[(2011, ''), (2012, ''), (2016, 'M'), (2016, 'J')]` Still not a nice solution but at least you don't see the word "NaN" on the plot.

Comment: hmm...Thats interesting. I did try the similar to avoid NaN, however still the bracket appear on the graph. But, your method gave an idea to produce a graph like the above.